# Why does Excel stop a macro when using Application.Evaluate?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the `Application.Evaluate` function to test if a conditional formatting condition is true. However, what is happening is that the macro just stops - no error message, and the cell in which the UDF is referenced returns #VALUE.

The value of the conditional formula `Formula1` property in this instance is  `"=A1<>VLOOKUP($A1,actWOrders1!$A:$EF,COLUMN(A1),FALSE)"`

I've tried replacing `Application.Evaluate` with `ActiveWorksheet.Evaluate`, in case it is the Application form is struggling with the context, but the same happens.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?

Thanks! Screwtape.

Comment: Is your formula CF the table, to show which one's aren't a1? or if A1 is in a table, then same for a2.....a1000000?  Match would be more efficient on a single column array, you're only looking at column A, but taking A:EF into the formula.  try if iserr(Match(a1,actWOrders1!$A:$EF,0)

Answer (score 0):

If your macro doesn't contain any `on error` handing statements it would certainly provide you with an error message if at any point it was unable to execute. It could be that your macro is executing completely however is not achieving the result you expect.

Try running it step by step using <kbd>F8</kbd> and observing what is happening on each line to find the culprit, as you step through you can hover your cursor over a number of items such as variables to see what their value is. You might also find reading [this webpage](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) will help you to use the tools in VBA to debug your macros.

Answer (score 0):

### You created a circular reference.

If you try and type the formula into a cell Excel will tell you that has a circular reference.

You can also step through a formula in the formula bar.

Highlight an expression in the formula that you want the value of

[image]

Press [F9] to calculate the expression

[image]

The expression will be replaced with its value